# Ruby: Factorial Recursion

Tags: ruby

The difference between the two methods occurs at second if condition. The if condition in the first method is "if num <= 1" and the if condition in the second method is "if num = 1". I mapped out both methods on a piece of paper step by step but I don't understand why the factorial2 returns 1 instead of 6. On paper, I get 6 for both methods.

```
def factorial1(num)
    if num < 0
        return "Please use a positive number"
    end

    if num <= 1
        1
    else
        num * factorial(num-1)
    end
end
puts factorial1(3)
#returns 6
def factorial2(num)
    if num < 0
        return "Please use a positive number"
    end

    if num = 1
        1
    else
        num * factorial(num-1)
    end
end
puts factorial2(3)
#returns 1
```

Comment: You meed to change `factorial(num-1)` to `factorial(num-1)` in `factorial` and to `factorial2(num-1)` in `factorial2`. After changing `=` to `==` in `factoria2` (as @kyflare points out) you still have a problem with `factorial2(0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if num = 1
```

Comparator operator is `==`, not `=` (assignment operator).

Also don't forget to use return keyword, it is good convention to make each branch return something.

Comment: Using the `return` keyword in Ruby is generally avoided unless needed like in the question, for early exit/flow control purposes.

Comment: using `return` is debate-ably non-ruby-like, but you definitely should make sure that the last operation/value in the method is the one you wish to return

Answer (score -1):

```
def fact(n)

return 1 if n==0

return n * fact(n-1)    
end  

puts "Enter number"

n=gets.to_i

a=fact(n)
puts a
```